# How to remove all not float numbers and duplicates from list

Tags: python, list

I have such list:

```
setter_maping = ['14.99', '0.0', '226.95', '0.0', '14.99', 'None', '0.0']
```

How can I get such list (to remove all duplicates, zeros, Nones... in one word : to remove all what is not float number like 22.22 or 15.66 etc, if I will have there 0.0, or any thing that is not compatible with pattern of number.number (11.1 , 11.11) such value should be deleted):

```
result = ['14.99', '226.95']
```

I have done simple:

```
kick_off = ['None', '0.0']
[mapped_prices.remove(i) for i in set_map if i in kick_off]
```

But how to produce more unified pattern for removing wrong values?
Can regex provide me solution? which regex will solve this? I have no experience with this module

Comment: There's a first time for everything. Go to regular-expressions.info and read the tutorial.

Comment: To remove duplicates from a list you should always think about using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: @MrAlias: what about `['19.2', '19.200']`?

Comment: @GregS that is a good point. I did not mean to say a set alone would be the solution to the problem.

Comment: What about numbers like `'12'`?

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction such numbers are useful for me, they should be converted to float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a set to remove duplicates, then remove anything else you don't want:

```
import re
result = set(['17.99', '0.0', '26.95', '26.95', '17.99', 'None', '0.0'])
result = [item for item in result if re.match('\d+\.\d+$', item)]
result = [item for item in result if float(item) != 0.0]
```

Comment: I wasn't the down vote, but maybe I can give some feedback. The comparison of `None` and `'None'` is False.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Didn't realize it wasn't literal. Still don't get why down vote and not just comment with that.

Comment: @Eli thanks, but what if there will be 17.999 in values along with 17.99, I need to have 2 values in result all time

Comment: @Eli I have tested this and your solution not provides now result what I need

Comment: This feels a little limited. What about '0.00'?

Comment: @smith: I don't see that part in your question. Can you explain what you want to happen in situations where your rules would return more than 2 items?

Comment: @Eli when Im running your code, Im getting in result 17.99 and 0.0 , need 17.99 and 26.95

Comment: @Eli sorry, now with regexp much better

Comment: @timgeb true. didn't realize he meant there would be other stuff of the sort there. Fixed to account for anything equal to 0. Still just 4 lines.

Comment: @smith try now. Anything missing?

Comment: @Eli no, works well , but why are u using result as a name 2 times for comprehension?

Comment: @smith to overwrite it in memory. Shouldn't matter much if your list is small, so in that case you could use different names to improve readability.

Comment: nitpicking: won't work if there can be mutable objects in the original list, but I assume that is not the case here. Good answer if the order of the result is irrelevant.

Comment: This fails on an input of `1.2e+19`. Regex for this task is using a sledgehammer to swat flies.

Comment: @msw there was no indication OP would be using anything like that, and he specifically asked for Regex. If he had to deal with complex representations like in your example, I'd agree with you, but if not, I'd prefer to keep the code short and simple as above.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for any non-float value, not only `None` or `'None'`, and will also preserve the original order:

```
set_map = ['17.99', '0.0', '26.95', '26.95', '17.99', 'None', '0.0']
seen = {0}
new_map = []
for item in set_map:
     try:
         flitem = float(item)
     except ValueError:
         continue
     if flitem not in seen:
         seen.add(flitem)
         new_map.append(item)

print(new_map)
```

Additionally, strings such as '0' or '0.000000' won't make it into the new list.

Comment: vise solution @timgeb , I forgot to say that I need always 2 item in result, but your variant works well

Comment: This is exactly doing what the OP specified, I'd like the downvote to be explained, thanks.

Comment: Seems a bit long for a pretty simple problem. Why use 11 lines of more complicated code when you could use 4? Also, this doesn't solve OPs problem. He asked for strings in the output. You're giving him floats.

Comment: @Eli ah, thanks for pointing out that there are strings in the expected result, I overlooked that. I adjusted my code accordingly. In addition, your solution using a set is better if the original order does not need to be preserved, but I was of the impression that it should be preserved. I also assumed that there can be mutable objects in the original list, then a TypeError will be thrown when you try to make it a set.

Answer (score 2):

@timgeb: Your Answer is accurate, but you can use just set:

```
set_map = ['17.99', '0.0', '26.95', '26.95', '17.99', 'None', '0.0']
new_map = []
for item in set(set_map):
    try:
        item = float(item)
        if item > 0: new_map.append(item)
    except ValueError:
        continue

new_map
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert to floats to get rid of ambiguities in text representation ('12.34' versus '0012.3400')
- Use a `for` because exceptions may need to be caught
- Use a set to filter out duplicates.

Usually I'd prefer a list comprehension, but that doesn't work well with having to catch exceptions. In this case for the `float()` conversion.

```
In [1]: data = ['17.99', '0.0', '26.95', '26.95', '17.99', 'None', '0.0']

In [2]: nw = set()

In [3]: for j in data:
   ...:     try:
   ...:         k = float(j)
   ...:         if k:
   ...:             nw.add(k)
   ...:     except ValueError:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

In [4]: print nw
set([0.0, 26.95, 17.99])

In [5]: list(nw)
Out[5]: [0.0, 26.95, 17.99]
```

Comment: This does not preserve the original order (I'm not sure that's a requirement, but I think it is) and still contains a 0.0.